# Offline public transportation trip planning for Rome

Tags: public-transport, transportation, maps, rome, atac

I'm going to Rome, and I want to use just public transportation. However, Google Maps doesn't offer the transportation services in the offline mode, it just offers to save the street map.

How can I best learn the streets, which buses to take, how to go back to the hostel every day, and so on? Is there anything I can download and print?

Comment: You'll find very expensive maps in most souvenir shops and newsagent stands. Personally [I'd download the PDF's from the ATAC website](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/61946/22140) on your mobile phone.

Answer (score 3):

ATAC (the company responsible for public transport in Rome) publish PDF maps showing bus lines for the [entire city](http://www.atac.roma.it/files/doc.asp?r=2) and in the [centre](http://www.atac.roma.it/files/doc.asp?r=3). The first of these will require either a rather large sheet of paper or very good eyesight if you're going to print the whole thing :-). There's also a separate map for [night buses](http://www.atac.roma.it/files/doc.asp?r=358).

While the routes are accurate as far as I know, the timetables published by ATAC should not be taken too literally. (In any case, they only give the departure time from the end of the line, rather than at each stop.)

Comment: Save the PDF's to your mobile and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Moovit in the [4.0 announcement](http://moovitapp.com/blog/say-hello-to-moovit-4-0/):

> Offline Support: Temporarily lost internet connection? No problem. Moovit stores any planned trip, including all of its directions and line information, maps and schedules for easy offline access when you need it.